# Tietze transformation

Tags: transformation, group-presentation

I have a  question in which I have to transform
$\textbf{I.}$ $\langle a,b,c \mid b^2, (bc)^2\rangle$

to

$\textbf{II.}$ $\langle x,y,z\mid y^2, z^2\rangle$

using Tietze transformations.

My attempt- 
$\langle a,b,c \mid b^2, (bc)^2\rangle \overset{1}{\rightarrow}\langle b,c \mid b^2, (bc)^2\rangle \overset{2}{\rightarrow}\langle x,b,c \mid b^2, (bc)^2\rangle \overset{3}{\rightarrow}\langle x,y,b,c \mid y^{-1}b,  b^2, (bc)^2\rangle \overset{4}{\rightarrow}\langle x, y, c \mid y^2, (yc)^2\rangle \overset{5}{\rightarrow}\text{ ?} $

Is my step $4$ correct, can I do it as I have defined $y$ as $b$ so I can remove $b$ and replace it by $y$? If it is correct what should be my step $5$?

Comment: I changed $<a,b,c,\ |\ b^2,(bc)^2>$ to $\langle a,b,c,\mid b^2,(bc)^2\rangle$.  That is standard usage.

Comment: For future reference, to get $\langle$ and $\rangle$, use the commands \langle and \rangle. It is much cleaner than $<$ and $>$.

Comment: By the way, in your step 1 you are removing the generator $a$. You can only do that when there is a relation that expresses $a$ as a word in the other generators. This is not the case in $\langle a,b,c|\ b^2, (bc)^2\rangle$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\langle a,b,c|\ b^2,(bc)^2\rangle&=\langle a,b,c,z|\ b^2,z^2, b^{-1}z=c\rangle\\&=\langle a,b,z|\ b^2,z^2\rangle\end{align}$$

In the first step we added a generator $z=bc$. Then the relation $(bc)^2=1$, becomes $z^2=1$, and need to put the relation $z=bc$, which we write as $b^{-1}z=c$.

In the second step we remove the generator $c$, taking away the relation $c=b^{-1}z$, which only defines $c$.

Comment: Doing this I finally got $\langle a,y,z\ | y^2, z^2 \rangle$. Now I have to add $x$ and remove $a$ , How that will be done as I cant remove $a$ without having  a relation expressing $a$ in terms of others. Also to add $x$ I will need to define it in relator.

Comment: Essentially you need to rename $a$ as $x$. This renaming can be seen as $\langle a\rangle=\langle a,x|x=a\rangle=\langle x\rangle$. (I ignored writting the $y$ and $z$ because they are not important here) The first step is introduction of a new generator equal to some word in the original generators $x=a$. The second step is removing a generator $a$, which is expressed by one of the relations as a word in the other generators $a=x$.

Comment: ohh yeah. Thanks a lot sir...